# Where is the file directory of blender modifiers python code?

Tags: python, modifiers

I kinda want to experiment with remesh modifier, and mess up with it's code. So I just want to know where it's python code located. Is it in C:/Users/UserName/Appdata/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender ? Also I want to know.. if I edit the code, will my blender crash or corrupted if I run the modifier. Thank you for response ^^.

Comment: Modifiers are not written in Python

Comment: That and also if you ever want to view something that is in python you can right click and then "edit source"... https://streamable.com/ppqh8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiers need to be able to deal with a huge volume of data, which is one of the reasons why Blender has them implemented in C.

In short, there is no Python code for the modifiers.

If you modify the C code for the modifiers & build your own Blender, then yes, there is a chance that Blender will crash (same as any other modification of its code; this is not limited to modifiers).

Comment: I'm really new to blender python prog. , thanks for helping me ^^